# In fluid dynamics does $u_x-v_y$ have a name?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, terminology, atmospheric-science

I have come across the quantity:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$
of the two dimensional velocity field $(u,v)$. Does this quantity have a name or is it related to any quantity with a name?

Comment: Isn't it $u_y-v_x$? That would be a curl of the vector field $(u,v)$ and that's of major importance in fluid dynamics.

Comment: Thats the [Vorticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity) isn't it?

Comment: @Diracology No, I do specifically mean $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$

Comment: See [this](http://abe-research.illinois.edu/faculty/dickc/Engineering/xmpdiffanala.htm)...hope it helps. I'll keep looking

Comment: also looks similar to [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZKIqDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=(%E2%88%82u+/+%E2%88%82x)+-+(%E2%88%82v+/+%E2%88%82y)+of+two+dimensional+velocity+field+(u,+v)&source=bl&ots=KTYh0GF-zk&sig=e8sPe47rf5okTRUoTfDeJrC33no&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjs6cKprJTOAhWsy4MKHSv3C7EQ6AEIJTAF#v=onepage&q=(%E2%88%82u%20%2F%20%E2%88%82x)%20-%20(%E2%88%82v%20%2F%20%E2%88%82y)%20of%20two%20dimensional%20velocity%20field%20(u%2C%20v)&f=false)

Comment: Pearson and Middleman use the elongational viscosity to relate a similar deformation tensor to the normal stress difference (in 3D though), see Pearson, Middleman; AIChE J Vol 23 No 5 (1977). In which context have you come across this quantity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This quantity is called the **Stretching deformation**.  The reference (1) given below says the following about it:

> Stretching deformation, $D^{(1)}$, is a measure of the deformation of a fluid element due to compression in one direction and simultaneous dilation in a direction orthogonal (90 degrees) to it.

Here by deformation it seems to be referring directly to a change in shape rather then also including changes in areas. This is because the quantity above is zero when the shape is kept the same but the area varied.

**Reference**

(1) Mak, M. 2011. *Atmospheric Dynamics*. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (page 50 [Link to Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0kp6HfWTAKAC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=%22stretching%20deformation%22%20Physical%20meaning&source=bl&ots=uZcsKf7qfO&sig=zN5uviD4LnUds-jJWxArvjq9_LY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7hK3w_p3OAhUEVRoKHUMVAVwQ6AEIMTAD#v=onepage&q=%22stretching%20deformation%22%20Physical%20meaning&f=false))