# A taylor expansion for fluids

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence

A while back I asked the question [In fluid dynamics does $u_x-v_y$ have a name?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/270244/in-fluid-dynamics-does-u-x-v-y-have-a-name/270897#270897). The reason for my question was due to it's presence in the following Taylor expansion about the orgin (see (1)):
$$\newcommand{\p}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} \newcommand{\f}[2]{\frac{ #1}{ #2}} \newcommand{\l}[0]{\left(} \newcommand{\r}[0]{\right)} \newcommand{\mean}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}\newcommand{\e}[0]{\varepsilon} \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>} u(x,y)\approx u_0+\f{1}{2}x(u_x+v_y)+\f{1}{2}x(u_x-v_y)+\f{1}{2}y(v_x+u_y)-\f{1}{2}y(v_x-u_y)$$
$$v(x,y)\approx v_0+\f{1}{2}y(u_x+v_y)-\f{1}{2}y(u_x-v_y)+\f{1}{2}x(v_x+u_y)+\f{1}{2}x(v_x-u_y)$$
where all derivatives are evaluated at $x=y=0$ and each coefficient has a specific meaning as explained in (1). Now I know<sup>1</sup> that these equations have something to do with 2d turbulence but can find no information on the relation. Thus my question is this does the above expansions have a name (so I can look it up) and what is their relation to 2d turbulence?

**Reference**

(1) Mak, M. 2011. *Atmospheric Dynamics*. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (page 50 [Link to Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0kp6HfWTAKAC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=%22stretching%20deformation%22%20Physical%20meaning&source=bl&ots=uZcsKf7qfO&sig=zN5uviD4LnUds-jJWxArvjq9_LY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7hK3w_p3OAhUEVRoKHUMVAVwQ6AEIMTAD#v=onepage&q=%22stretching%20deformation%22%20Physical%20meaning&f=false))

<sub><sup>1</sup>From a source which is not publicly available and that goes into very little detail except mentioning the existence of such a relation.</sub>

Comment: What source is not publicly available? Is it behind a firewall or is it like a handwritten note on a book or something? In 2D, the $u_x + v_y$ term is just the dilation term, and for incompressible flows it will be zero -- but then $u_x - v_y$ would just be $2 u_x$ and so I assume this is related to compressible flows only. But I don't know why expanding things the way it is done there would be terribly useful.

Comment: @tpg2114 they are old notes on a server only accessible thru my uni. (I have  provided as much information if not more then in those notes), although I think it's relation to turbulence is to do with the follows in the following paper http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2153-3490.1955.tb01147.x/pdf (pdf page 7)

Comment: The only other relation I can think of that may matter: if it is 2D, you have a stream function $\psi$ such that $u = \psi_y$ and $v = \psi_x$. In that case, $u_x - v_y = 2 \psi_{xy}$. In that situation, $u \approx u_0 + x \psi_{xy} + ...$ and $v \approx v_0 - y \psi_{xy}$. What that gets you that you didn't already know... not sure I have any idea. I haven't found this quantity in any other place, and the link to the *Atmospheric Dynamics* book says that page is blocked for me.